# To open a little pop up window on a click to display html content on ie8. Not all content is seen in the window

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open a little pop window on a right click that displays html content using javascript.

It does open a pop up window-ie8 with the given dimensions. I don't want to hardcode any of the values for height and width. Based on the loaded content it should automatically be resized or it should allow the user to resize the pop'd up ie8 window at least, but it doesn't let me resize.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

below is the code

```
function opendinhtml(html, nm, wid, hei) {
    var w = 480,
        h = 340;
    if (document.all) {
        w = document.body.clientWidth;
        h = document.body.clientHeight;
    } else if (document.layers) {
        w = window.innerWidth;
        h = window.innerHeight;
    }
    var leftPos = (w - wid) / 2,
        topPos = (h - hei) / 2;
    var abcd = window.open("", nm, 'wid=' + wid + ',hei=' + hei + ',top=' + topPos + ',left=' + leftPos);
    abcd.document.open();
    abcd.document.write(htmlText);
    abcd.document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `sizeToContent()`:

```
abcd.sizeToContent();
```

but it's not likely to work. Modern browsers allow the user to assert complete authority over:

- when a new browser window gets opened
- what controls it will have
- what size it will be

From [MDN's FAQ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open#FAQ) about `window.open`

> **How do I resize a window to fit its content?**
>
> You can not reliably because the users can prevent the window from being resized by unchecking the Edit/Preferences/Advanced/Scripts & Plug-ins/Allow Scripts to/ Move or resize existing windows checkbox in Mozilla or Tools/Options.../Content tab/Enable Javascript/Advanced button/Move or resize existing windows checkbox in Firefox or by setting dom.disable_window_move_resize to true in about:config or by editing accordingly their user.js file.

There's more to read at the link, which I strongly suggest you do.

As a design consideration, pop-up browser windows went out of style around the same time as the Spice Girls (and with good reason). Have you considered a dialog instead (basically a `div` element overlayed on the page)? Contrasting with pop-ups, dialogs are:

- Easy to control
- Easy to resize
- Able to accept AJAX content
- Not subject to pop-up blockers
- Not really difficult to pull-off in plain-vanilla JavaScript
- A snap to pull off with a JavaScript DOM Manipulation library (like, but not limited to, jQuery)